# Not able to retrieve exact binary data from bmp image using C programming

Tags: c, image-processing, bmp

I was trying to get the exact binary data from a bmp image using C programming. Please find the code below. After excluding the header data I tried to copy the binary data to a new file but the data is wrong. I am trying to display the image (32 by 8) on LED board (32 by 8) using Arduino board. I am new to this. Could anyone please help me why the data is wrong. Please find the led_image also.

[image: led_image]

#### C program:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    FILE *ptr_bmp_in;
    FILE *ptr_text_out;
    int c;
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0;
    int imagesize = 0;
    int bits = 0;

    ptr_bmp_in = fopen("led_image.bmp", "rb");
    ptr_text_out = fopen("led_binary.txt", "w");

    if (!ptr_bmp_in)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(ptr_bmp_in, 0x12, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&width, 4, 1, ptr_bmp_in);
    printf("\n Width: %d", width);
    fseek(ptr_bmp_in, 0x16, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&height, 4, 1, ptr_bmp_in);
    printf("\n Height: %d", height);
    fseek(ptr_bmp_in, 0x36, SEEK_SET);

    imagesize = height * width;
    printf("\n Imagesize: %d", imagesize);

    while ((c = fgetc(ptr_bmp_in)) != EOF)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
        {
            if (c & (1 << (7 - i)))
            {
                fputc('1', ptr_text_out);
            }
            else
            {
                fputc('0', ptr_text_out);
            }
            bits++;
        }
        printf(" bits: %d", bits);
        if (bits >= imagesize) {
            printf("BREAK THE LOOP");
            break;
        }   
    }
    fclose(ptr_bmp_in);
    fclose(ptr_text_out);
    printf("Writing done\n");

    return 0;
}
```

#### Binary data:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
00000001000000010000000100000000
00000010000000100000001000000000
00000011000000110000001100000000
00000100000001000000010000000000
00000101000001010000010100000000
00000110000001100000011000000000
00000111000001110000011100000000
```

#### Expected Binary data: (as per the link https://www.dcode.fr/binary-image)

```
00000010000000000010000000000010
00000001000000000001000000000001
00000000100000000000100000000000
00000000010000000000010000000000
00000000001000000000001000000000
00000000000100000000000100000000
10000000000010000000000010000000
01000000000001000000000001000000
```

Comment: `fseek(ptr_bmp_in, 0x16, SEEK_SET);` Isn't the height supposed to be at `0x14`?

Comment: Nope, width is at 0x12 and height at 0x16 : assuming a DIB header. [See](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header).

Comment: Alas, your provided "led_image" is encoded as PNG on imgur, so I can't see the original. My attempt to convert it back to BMP turned it into a 24 bit image, which I think is not the format of the original.

Comment: OK, problem #1 is that bitmap rows are stored "bottom-up". So the 8th row is first, the 7th second, etc.

Comment: argh, took too long to edit. OK, one problem is that bitmap rows are stored "bottom-up". So the 8th row is first, the 7th second, etc. Put it another way, the first byte you read is actually the left 8 pixels of the *last* row.

Comment: @kaylum, height is at 0x14 if it's an OS/2 1.x bitmap header.  Windows BITMAPINFOHEADER has the height at 0x16. Easy to get confused, the Wikipedia entry is poorly laid out...

Comment: BMP also can have a color table, and your copied data look like a gray scale table. Decode the BMP according to all meta data.

Comment: Thanks Kaylum, Kevin and the busybee for looking into the issue.

Comment: @Kevin, Not sure why the image is seen as PNG but it is in BMP format only. Please find the image here. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XrdmHPx_IsN1BYBBW9A9TArL8lQuO_j8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Kevin, OK, if the rows are stored "bottom-up", the output will become like below. Still it would not match the expected output.
 00000111000001110000011100000000
 00000110000001100000011000000000
 00000101000001010000010100000000
 00000100000001000000010000000000
 00000011000000110000001100000000
 00000010000000100000001000000000
 00000001000000010000000100000000
 00000000000000000000000000000000

Comment: @the busy bee, OK, I tried with color table also.
As per the wiki, "The number of entries in the palette is either 2powerN (where N is the number of bits per pixel) or a smaller number specified in the header. In most cases, each entry in the color table occupies 4 bytes, in the order blue, green, red, 0x00." 

So, bits per pixel = 1 for monochrome. 2power1 * 4 (Each entry has 4 bytes) = 8bytes.

54 + 8 = 62 bytes(0x3E).

I tried to read the data after 62 bytes(0x3E) in rows in reverse order. Below is the output. Still does not match with expected output.

Comment: @the busy bee
00001001000010010000100100000000
00001000000010000000100000000000
00000111000001110000011100000000
00000110000001100000011000000000
00000101000001010000010100000000
00000100000001000000010000000000
00000011000000110000001100000000
00000010000000100000001000000000

Comment: In the meantime, please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" to learn how this site works. This is not a forum. Please [edit] your question and add new information there, down here in the comments they will get lost.

Comment: Oh, and providing files as an external resource (that additionally needs to login) is a bad idea, too. It will vanish soon, right? Since the image is really small, please consider to provide a hex dump. Most of us know how to convert a hex dump back to binary.

Comment: Could you accept the answer, please? Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin, yes sure. Done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having downloaded the file from the link, here is the cause of your problem.

The header bytes (14) are as follows:

`42 4D 38 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 04 00 00`

Breaking that down: as per Wikipedia:

- `42 4D` : "BM"
- `38 05 00 00` : file is 1336 bytes long
- next two words (4 bytes) required, zero
- `36 04 00 00` : offset to pixel data

To quote Indiana Jones: "They're digging in the wrong place!"

This:

`fseek(ptr_bmp_in, 0x36, SEEK_SET);`

needs to be:

`fseek(ptr_bmp_in, 0x0436, SEEK_SET);`

Pointless to speculate unless we have the actual file.